# Pandas hierarchical columns and csv functions

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to round-trip a DataFrame through csv in a way that respects hierarchical column structure? In other words, if I have the following DataFrame:

```
>>> cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"],
                                      ["a", "b", "c", "d"]])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), index=range(5), columns=cols)
```

Doing the following fails:

```
>>> df.to_csv("df.csv", index_label="index")
>>> df_new = pd.read_csv("df.csv", index_col="index")
>>> assert df.columns == df_new.columns
```

Am I missing some options in the csv save/read steps?

Comment: this is an open issue right now : https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1651

Answer (score 2):

In the special case where you have a columnar MultiIndex, but a simple index, you can transpose the DataFrame and use `index_label` and `index_col` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"],
                                  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), index=range(5), columns=cols)

(df.T).to_csv('/tmp/df.csv', index_label=['first','second'])
df_new = pd.read_csv('/tmp/df.csv', index_col=['first','second']).T
assert np.all(df.columns.values == df_new.columns.values)
```

But unfortunately this begs the question what to do if both the index and columns are MultiIndexes?

---

Here is one hacky workaround:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ast

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"],
                                  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), index=range(5), columns=cols)
print(df)

df.to_csv('/tmp/df.csv', index_label='index')
df_new = pd.read_csv('/tmp/df.csv', index_col='index')

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([ast.literal_eval(item) for item in df_new.columns])
df_new.columns = columns
df_new.index.name = None
print(df_new)
assert np.all(df.columns.values == df_new.columns.values)
```

---

Of course, if you just want to store the DataFrame in a file of any format, then `df.save` and `pd.load` provide a more pleasant solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"],
                                  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), index=range(5), columns=cols)

df.save('/tmp/df.df')
df_new = pd.load('/tmp/df.df')
assert np.all(df.columns.values == df_new.columns.values)
```